# oracle: aliasing problem, why isn't recognizing it?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

Ok guys, im having a real issue trying to understand the logic behind the aliasing in oracle. Here is the query:

```
select isbn,
       b.fname,
       b.lname
from   bookauthor a,
       author b,
       (select authorid auth
        from   bookauthor
        where  isbn = (select max(isbn) maxisbn
                       from   orderitems))
where  b.authorid = auth
       and isbn = maxisbn;
```

for some reason, the dbms isn't recognizing maxisbn as an alias, but if i get rid of everything regarding maxisbn, the query runs and recognizes the alias "auth" just fine. Why is it seeing one but not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`maxisbn` isn't the name of any column exposed by your derived table's `SELECT` list.

In order for this syntax to work you would need to add it as a column as below.

```
select isbn,
       b.fname,
       b.lname
from   bookauthor a,
       author b,
       (select authorid auth, isbn maxisbn
        from   bookauthor
        where  isbn = (select max(isbn) maxisbn
                       from   orderitems))
where  b.authorid = auth
       and isbn = maxisbn;
```

NB: There is <s>probably</s> definitely a more efficient way of writing this query (you shouldn't need to access `bookauthor` twice) and I would always use explicit `JOIN` syntax. This is just to answer your specific question about why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To take up Martin's question if this can be written more efficiently.

I think that the following will perform better and still return the same thing:

```
SELECT a.max_isbn,
       b.fname,
       b.lname
FROM  (SELECT authorid as max_authorid, 
              isbn as max_isbn
       FROM bookauthor
       WHERE isbn = (SELECT max(isbn) FROM orderitems)) a
  JOIN author b ON a.max_authorid = b.authorid AND a.max_isbn = b.isbn
```